# Run ajax request after input from another one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two ajax requests, one runs after the user types and then second one runs on the click from the user. I can run the first one without any issue, but when I do the click for the second, nothing happens? Can I run two AJAX requests, one after the other? Could there be an issue why the second requests never runs. Here is my code

In the sample below lookID runs when the user types and updateID when the user clicks the button

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ID Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            Update new user
        </div>
        <div id="dialog-form">
            <form style="text-align: center;">
                <fieldset style="border: none;">
                    <span class="searchDisplay" id="rst" style="padding: 10px 0px; display: inline;"></span> 
                    <span class="deleteicon"><input autocomplete="off" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all deletable" id="id" name="id" placeholder="xxx-xx" type="text"> <span></span></span>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
                <button aria-disabled="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" type="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Update ID</span></button> <button aria-disabled="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" type="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
                       $(document).ready(function() {
                       $(function() {
                          var dialog, form,
                              id = $("#id"),
                              allFields = $([]).add(name),
                              tips = $(".validateTips");

                          function updateTips(t) {
                              tips.text(t).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                              setTimeout(function() {
                                  tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
                              }, 500);
                          }

                          function checkID() {
                               if ($("#validity").html() == "Valid ID") {
                                   updateID($("#id").val());
                               }
                               else {
                                   alert("Please use a valid id");
                               }
                               var valid = true;
                               allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                               return valid;
                          }
                          dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                              autoOpen: false,
                              width: 350,
                              modal: true,
                              buttons: {
                                  "Update Id": checkID,
                                  Cancel: function() {
                                      dialog.dialog("close");
                                  }
                              },
                              close: function() {
                                  form[0].reset();
                                  allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                              }
                          });
                          form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
                              event.preventDefault();
                              checkID();
                          });
                          $("#create-user").button().on("click", function() {
                              dialog.dialog("open");
                          });
                       });

                       $("input.deletable").wrap("<span class=\"deleteicon\" />").after($("<span/>").click(function() {
                           $(this).prev("input").val("").focus();
                           $("#rst").html("");
                       }));


                       $("input.deletable").keyup(function() {
                           runSearch();
                       });
                   });
                    function updateID(user_id) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://sample.com/ajax-functions.php",
                            data: "ajax=create&id="+user_id,
                            type: "POST",
                            success:function(html) {
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    function runSearch() {
                        var values = $("input.deletable").values();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://sample.com/ajax-functions.php",
                            data: "ajax=search&id="+values,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(html){
                                $("#div_rst").slideDown();
                                $("#div_rst").addClass("searchDisplay");
                                $("#div_rst").html(html);
                            }
                        });
                    }                  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if($_POST['ajax'] == 'create') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $return = '<script>alert("' . $id . '")</script>';

}

else if ($_POST['ajax'] == 'search') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $return = '<div style="height:10px;max-width:100%;">';

    if ($id) {
        $return .= '<div id="validity">Valid ID</div>';
    }
    else {
        $return .= '<div id="validity">Invalid ID</div>';
    }
    $return .= '</div>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the second one doesn't run? You are returning some HTML with a `script` tag and an `alert()`, but in your success function you don't do anything. You would need to add the HTML to the page for any result. As a test, you could add `alert(html);` inside your success function and see if anything happens.

It also looks like your `updateID()` function uses the param `user_id` but in your data you are passing `id`. That's probably a mistake?

It might also be a good idea to give us some complete code that we can actually run; based on the above, how do we know if the function is even being called?

Comment: I only have the alert for testing purposes, I have tried HTML output and nothing runs

Comment: It would be best to set up a full, testable example then. There are too many "maybes" to know for sure. Did you try putting an alert inside of your success function to see if anything did in fact get returned? Is there other JS running that could have errored and stopped further scripts from running on the page? There is nothing in JS that would prevent you from doing what you are trying to do other than a bug somewhere.

Comment: I added the full HTML in case it helps

Comment: You haven't addressed the other questions I asked. Please provide a minimal testable solution (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help.